# Adding child elements (divs) to a parent element (div), how can I stop each child affecting the top value of the child after it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

In [this jQuery code](http://jsfiddle.net/heQFB/), I am dynamically adding boxes to the canvas div like this:

```
var canvas = $('#canvas');
canvas.append('<div id="1"></div>');
('#1').addClass('ui-boxer')
                .css({ border: '1px solid white',
                       background: 'orange',
                       padding: '0.5em',
                       position: 'relative',
                       'z-index': 100,
                       left: '1%', top: '10%',
                       width: '40%', height: '50%'});

canvas.append('<div id="2"></div>');
$('#2').addClass('ui-boxer')
                .css({ border: '1px solid white',
                       background: 'orange',
                       padding: '0.5em',
                       position: 'relative',
                       'z-index': 100,
                       left: '50%', top: '10%',
                       width: '20%', height: '50%'});
```

The boxes are created okay, but the top position of the second box is wrong. It's 10% (like the first box), but it's clearly not working correctly. I think the presence of the first child is affecting it? How can I set the top value so that it is based of the parent element (the canvas div) and not the child element before it? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Your code above should bring a error `('#1').addClass('ui-boxer')` should have been `$('#1').addClass('ui-boxer')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changed the position to absolute.

Check this
http://jsfiddle.net/heQFB/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem with using absolute is that the box top and left parameters are no longer relative to the canvas div, eg http://jsfiddle.net/2ABVY/

Comment: @ben - Wrap the canvas tag in a div that is `position: relative` and thus the absolute positions are actually absolute to the relative div.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using absolute positioning. Set the positioning of the canvas div to relative (e.g. `<div id="canvas" style="position: relative;"></div>`), and set your child divs to absolute, i.e.:

```
$(function() {

var canvas = $('#canvas');
canvas.append('<div id="1"></div>');
$('#1').addClass('ui-boxer')
                .css({ border: '1px solid white',
                       background: 'orange',
                       padding: '0.5em',
                       position: 'absolute',
                       'z-index': 100,
                       left: '1%', top: '10%',
                       width: '40%', height: '50%'});

canvas.append('<div id="2"></div>');
$('#2').addClass('ui-boxer')
                .css({ border: '1px solid white',
                       background: 'orange',
                       padding: '0.5em',
                       position: 'absolute',
                       'z-index': 100,
                       left: '50%', top: '10%',
                       width: '20%', height: '50%'});
});
```

Comment: Quite Unique Answer! Dont you think?